# Looking for library of resources on real product's design, Information Architecture, etc

Tags: navigation, design-patterns, design, information-architecture, product-design

For my current project, I am looking for inspiration related to how different digital products (web applications, mobile apps) are organized:
navigation + menu structure, Information Architecture

So far I have been looking for tools myself, creating accounts to go inside and explore myself. It's time-consuming and I have a feeling that I might miss many of the tools that would be relevant for me.

I wonder if there is any library where I can look for this type of stuff. I am not interested in a library of general UI patterns or Dribbble, I want the "real" stuff.

Comment: Wouldn't a browse through a list of design systems give you a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what I was looking for - a tool called Mobbin which is a library  of different types of pages across various products